# Help Improving Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posed a question which received 11 views and no responses.  While it's possible that no one knows the answer, I'm open to the possibility that it's how I worded the question.

Please review the question [Windows 7 Answerfile - Autologon Not Working](https://superuser.com/questions/747081/windows-7-answerfile-autologon-not-working). Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you've asked a valid, on-topic question, including info on what you've tried and what you are trying to do.

Overall I think the question is fine. You could break the first paragraph up into some more paragraphs to make it easier to read, but other than that, all the relevant info is there. I've upvoted it. I just don't know the answer.

You only asked it 7 hours ago. Some people who may know the answer could have been asleep during the entire time since you asked it. Before asking a meta question like this, you may want to wait at least a couple of days to see if it gets answered or at least have someone point you in the right direction with a comment. In my opinion you are asking this meta question *too soon* after the question was originally posted.

But the question is good. Very good, in fact, compared to the average/typical question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback It's much appreciated!  And also thank you for helping to set the right expectation :)

Comment: If you haven't gotten any answers after (I think) 2 days -- the minimum length of time required to set a bounty -- you can either offer some of your own reputation as a bounty, or if you remind me here, I'll offer some of mine (since I have a much larger reputation pool than you). Bounty tends to get a lot of answers from people who are good at researching problems but may not know the answer off the top of their head -- in other words, they'll put in more effort to answer it, instead of reading it and going "ah, I don't know".